# Is it normal to interview for faculty positions in December-February and not hear back yet by the end of March?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I had several interviews in December-February in R1 universities for tenure-track assistant professor positions in a life sciences field.

I was told that they would get back to me in March, so I emailed them and some have not replied back and some said to wait some more.

So, I was wondering if this is normal to wait for that long or "the ship has sailed" and I'm not getting any offers :(

Comment: I removed the part that was polling about other people's offers this year, since that's off topic here.

Comment: You may well be a second or third choice.  In that case, they're probably keeping you as a backup in case they can't reach agreement with their top choice, and its likely that they're in negotiations with another candidate.  FWIW, I interviewed for my current position in early March and didn't get an offer until late May after two others had turned down the job.

Comment: I find the waiting to be torturous, any advice on how to take your mind off that?

Answer (score 5):

Commiserations -- the job search is tough.

If they haven't gotten back to you by the time they said they would, it most likely means you are not their first preference candidate. They probably have already made an offer and are waiting to have that accepted or rejected. You could still get an offer as their second/third/fourth/etc. preference.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, you **never** hear back from a committee.

I applied for a position and had an interview *three years ago*, and have not had so much as an acknowledgment that the interview even take place, let alone a rejection notice.

Comment: Thank you, I guess without the official "No" I still keep living in hope and it's so hard to move on. I am actually having trouble focusing on my work and all I can think about is what went wrong. I need to snap out of it.

Comment: Was it by any chance a German university? I just received a negative answer from an university in Germany, where I applied more than two years ago. I don't know what I find more curious - that it took them two years to fill the position, or that somebody actually bothered sending out rejections multiple years after the application had been sent.

Comment: @xLeitix: Nope. It was a school in the USA.

Comment: @xLeitix two years!!! they didnt filled positon?

Comment: @SSimon they did... I think.